# share list between process c++

Tags: c++, list, ipc

I'm new to c++ and have a little problem.

So I have a UdpServeur which **receives** messages and I would like another program I wrote to use them.
So I used **FIFO tube** but it's very heavy for the code. Then I used locks with a simple .txt file but it's not very clean and not good for the project.

For my project people told me that I can use a list with a reference but I didn't really understand.

I'm pretty sure there is a very very simple way to make the programs interact with the same list without a lot of effort...
Please Help me ! :D
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use shared memory if you're brave, but this is not always as easy as it sounds. You'd be better off using threads vs. multiple processes if you can swing it, and even that is a bit harrowing.

Comment: By "FIFO tubes" I assume you mean *pipes*? They are generally not "heavy". I would say it's easier to use pipes than UDP sockets.

Comment: @tadman thank you tadman for your answer , I tried Shared memory and i passed the whole day yesterday doing it for a pretty bad result. So in the case i have multiple threads running i just have to use a list with a reference that's it ?

Comment: Threads make it way easier to share data, but if this data isn't `const` it can be tricky to orchestrate changes with mutexes and such. If it's just a look-up table, why not dump it to a file and then both processes can use that instead? If it's constantly changing you may be better off using a proper client/server model for IPC.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My pipes make me use 2 temporary files. It's a big project and i will have a lot of IPC so i cant have that much files. Maybe I wasnt clear but i have a client.serveur talking in UDP that's another part but i would like the messages receive by the server to be put in a share list with another thread/process...

Comment: How many different IPC channels will you have open simultaneously? What are your worries about the "files" for the pipes? That they will become to large (that's not how FIFOs work) or that there will be too many of them (why not reuse or remove the FIFO files once you're done with them)? Will the IPC channels be used for short bursts of data, or open for longer time? How are the processes related, will there be one parent process which creates a set of child processes? Then how about anonymous (non-file) pipes, or `socketpair`?

Comment: If you have one producer and one consumer on the same machine and little lattency, the *common* way is a simple pipe if processes are related or a named pipe (or unix domain socket) if they are not. If you want to be able to stop the consumer without losing messages, then you would implement a disk pool *somewhere*. I have never seen a project where the complexity prevented to add one single pipe (at least since I no longer use MS/DOS).

Comment: @SergeBallesta I did the producer/consumer method and it worked pretty good with only one file on my computer. however the supervisor for this project doesn't want that thing and he think i could do something like i show with the example below , do you think its possible or i should stay with my one file sharing the text?

Comment: @et11enne: *one file sharing the text* cannot be a simple design because of the synchronization problems. Sharing a list between **threads** is of course a possible design (do not forget a mutex for synchronization). It you want different processes, sharing a list is still possible but it would require a custom allocator using a shared memory segment. As you say that you are new to C++, keep away for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [lock guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is not complex, and you even do not need to care about releasing it.

```
std::mutex list_mutex; 

// Access from thread 1:
{
   std::lock_guard guard(list_mutex);
   // Work with the list
}

// Access from thread 2:
{
   std::lock_guard guard(list_mutex);
   // Work with the list
}
```

Both list and list_mutex must be declared somewhere where both threads could see them. As soon as the execution leaves the curved brace area (also using return or throwing exceptions), the lock guard would be released.